# Mongoose: How to update array of objects using the "$in" operator?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    notifications: [{
        title: {type: String},
        text: {
            type:String
        },
        seen: {type: Boolean},
        link: {type: String} 
    }]
})
```

I have an array of ids, lets call it arrayOfIds, where each _id matches one of the Objects in the notifications array. I want to update all the objects (in notifications array) which match the ids in arrayOfIds. Here is how I am currently doing it:

```
const doc = await Notifications.updateMany(
            {_id: req.user.notifications, "notifications._id": {"$in": arrayOfIds}},
            {
                $set: {
                    "notifications.$.seen": true
                }
            },
            {
                multi: true
            }

        )
```

req.user.notifications is the ObjectId of the entire document. Whereas notification is a field in that document and I want to update all entries in the notifications field which match with the arrayOfIds.
For some reason, this query is only updating the one object in the notifications array instead of matching all Ids from arrayOfIds.
Could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong? I cannot understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with `mongoose` and my question may be completely ridiculous, but where in the schema/document does `"notifications._id"` appear?

Comment: You can try using the Array Update Operators along with the update method's `arrayFilters` option. Also, you can use the `collection.updateMany` method, instead of specifying the `multi` option.

Comment: Could you build an example query with array filters?